Failed to use `top` after trying to install htop
My machine:
cat /etc/os-release

gives
...
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VERSION_ID="7.2"


The error currently:
$top 
'xterm-256color': unknown terminal type.

What I tried:

modify term, TERM, TERMINFO such as:

export TERM=xterm
export TERMINFO=/usr/share/terminfo


install ncurces

wget https://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/ncurses/ncurses-6.2.tar.gz
tar xzf ncurses-6.2.tar.gz
cd ncurses-6.2
./configure --prefix=/opt/ncurses
make
make install

Neither works.
